# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/search/IndexSpec

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-search-api

I am using Google App Engine along with Google Datastore and Google Search Api as the backend solution for my App.

Everything has been working fine until 3 days ago when I made a small modification and deployed my code. Then I encountered issues as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService. I am pretty sure the change I made has nothing to do with this, so I read google document (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/) and find that I need to use Google Cloud Client Library instead of app engine apis. so I added following code in my gradle and started using Client Library for datastore.

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:1.98.0'
```

But this only fix issue for datastore, the issue for search api still exist. For search, I followed document at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/ , and I cannot find the replacement solution for it with Google Cloud Client Library (as listed: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients).

I also read the document for Google Api Client Library (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis), also cannot find the solution.

my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.11"
    }
}

version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"

    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:+'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11"

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:1.98.0'

    compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
}

appengine {
    deploy {   // deploy configuration

    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: From the title's error I understand that you are using this [API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/IndexSpec). Have you included it also in your code? Could you please post your gradle file in order to inspect it?

Comment: Also could you mention what change did you do as it may be relevant to the error somehow?

Comment: @tzovourn the change I made is purely business logic, I didn't change my dependency at all

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example of your code in order for me to reproduce it?